# jquery file Tree using php

Tags: php, jquery

using awesome jquery File Tree and needed to modify the php code but not getting much luck.

Below is the code and what I am looking for is once I am at file level, how can I PWD to get complete path? I don't think it is possible as I naively thought I could just store previous found value to variable(but guess the way this thing gets called, they call this php completely so variable never retains.. Any other idea?

```
$_POST['dir'] = urldecode($_POST['dir']);

if( file_exists($root . $_POST['dir']) ) {
    $files = scandir($root . $_POST['dir']);
    natcasesort($files);
    if( count($files) > 2 ) { /* The 2 accounts for . and .. */
        echo "<ul class=\"jqueryFileTree\" style=\"display: none;\">";
        // All dirs
        foreach( $files as $file ) {
            if( file_exists($root . $_POST['dir'] . $file) && $file != '.' && $file != '..' && is_dir($root . $_POST['dir'] . $file) ) {
                echo "<li class=\"directory collapsed\"><a href=\"#\" rel=\"" . htmlentities($_POST['dir'] . $file) . "/\">" . htmlentities($file) . "</a></li>";
            }
        }
        // All files
        foreach( $files as $file ) {
            if( file_exists($root . $_POST['dir'] . $file) && $file != '.' && $file != '..' && !is_dir($root . $_POST['dir'] . $file) ) {
                $ext = preg_replace('/^.*\./', '', $file);
                echo "<li class=\"file ext_$ext\"><a href=\"#\" rel=\"" . htmlentities($_POST['dir'] . $file) . "\">" . htmlentities($file) . "</a></li>";
            }
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) what you're looking for? Your question isn't very easy to understand.

Comment: So say I traversed /dir1/dir2/dir3/filename... and when I get to filename.. I want to recover all the parent directory name.. Is there anyway ??

Comment: Have you tried `dirname($root . $_POST["dir"] . $file)`?

Comment: YOUR post was one of the clutchest post ever.. thank you so MUCH.. that was it

Comment: Glad to have helped, although I realised the `dirname` function is redundant in this case - the directory is already written out in the code: `$root . $_POST["dir"]`.